# deleting a form deletes all the created form

Tags: jquery

I am unable to delete only one form at a time. In my code, I am able to add forms. But when I want to delete only one form at a time, all the forms that have been created gets deleted except for the first form. My code so far:

```
<div>
<form class="form" action="" method="" > 
  product:<input type="text">
  price:<input type="text">
  <button class="r">remove</button>
</form>
</div>


<div class="class"> </div>
<button class="add"> add </button>
```

jquery:

```
$('.add').on('click', function(){
var $clone = $('.form').clone();
$('.class').append( $clone ); 

}); 

$('.r').on('click', function(){ 
$('this').parent('form').remove();
//$('this').parent('div').remove();// even this gives the same result

});
```

Thanks. You were right. i got the answer.

Comment: Do you want to remove the first or the last form created?

Comment: `on` needs to be delegated in order to handle events from dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `$('this')` is not `$(this)`. But that is not the only problem.

Your "remove" function was only applied to the first '.r' element and because you don't do a deep clone (you don't want to also copy the values) the event listener will not be cloned as well.

I recommend using event delegation `$(document).on('click', '.r', ...` which binds the event listener to the document (you can increase specificity to reduce overhead if possible) and listen for events on elements matching a selector (in this case '.r').

Also, because a button will cause the form to submit, you have to make sure to return `false` (or use the event's `.preventDefault()` method) to stop the form from submitting if the button is inside a form.

Finally, you should cache your jQuery objects if you use them more than once to limit overhead.

```js
var form = $('.form');
var target = $('.target');
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    target.append(form.clone());
});
$(document).on('click', '.r', function(){ 
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form class="form" action="" method=""> 
        product:<input type="text">
        price:<input type="text">
        <button class="r">remove</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="target"></div>
<button class="add">add</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am still facing the same problem. I have used your full code and same thing happens. I have posted my full code.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I forgot to stop the button from submitting the form. [Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/gegodebujo/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here are the things to keep in mind.
-- If you trying to append a dynamic html during an event, any corresponding events ( such clicks ) needs to be referenced in the same function.
Also, Since you are using the buttons for add-remove and not submitting a form, you can replace those with regular input type of button.

```
<div>
<form class="form" action="" method="" > 
  product:<input type="text">
  price:<input type="text">
  <input type="button" class="r" value="Remove"/>
    </form>
</div>


<div class="class"> </div>
<input type="button" class="add" value="Add"/>

$('.add').on('click', function(){
var $clone = $('.form').clone();
$('.class').append( $clone ); 
$('.r').on('click', function(e){ 
$(this).parent('.form').remove();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmyag5oe/

Comment: Thank you but I am still running into same problem.